# Android - How to set own text in Button/TextView using data-binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

I just started working around with android `data-binding`. And I wanted to change button text according user login status but I got below error.

Log says Syntax error, tried but I found nothing.
**Code**
[image]

**Logcat error**

> Error:|', '?', ':', '??'}
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Syntax error: mismatched input 'gin' expecting {'.', '::', '[', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '<<', '>>>', '>>', '<=', '>=', '>', '<', 'instanceof', '==', '!=', '&', '^', '|', '&&', '||', '?', ':', '??'}
>   file:C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\src\main\res\layout\binding_activity.xml
>   loc:30:28 - 30:61
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Any help will be appriciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation probably should be like:

```
user.isLogged ? @string/logout : @string/login
```

Answer (score 3):

As **Sherlock** says ["You see, but you do not observe. The distinction is clear"](http://sherlockholmesquotes.com/)

And what I did is, I did not observed the official document. you can set text like this also

> When using single quotes around the attribute value, it is easy to use double quotes in the expression:

```
  android:text='@{user.isLogged ? "Logout" : "Login"}'
```

> It is also possible to use double quotes to surround the attribute value. When doing so, String literals should either use the quote or back quote (`).

```
 android:text="@{user.isLogged ? `Logout` : `Login`}" //text is inside back-quote
```

[Data Binding Guide- String Literals](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#string_literals)